# Is it possible to put newlines in api documentation generated by Sami

Tags: php, phpdoc

**TL;DR**: How do I force a newline to be rendered by Sami?

I'm generating documentation with the Sami documentation generator. I've got one method commented like so:

```
/**
 * This method gets called by the Dispatcher's Event manager.
 * This component was added as a dispatch listener in bootstrap.php.
 *
 * @return  boolean TRUE if the current user is allowed to access the current action
 *                  FALSE if the current user is not allowed to access the current action, 
 *                  or if the action doesn't have an ACL entry
 */
```

The first 2 lines are rendered in the documentation on separate lines - great.

The explanation of the return value appears on 1 line.  I can put `<br />` at the end of the first line, but I think that looks hack-ish in PHP comments.  Sami seems to recognize Markdown italics & bold, but the double-space-at-end-of-line newline isn't recognized.

Is there another way to force newlines?

Comment: Have you tried PHP_EOL ?

Comment: @miknik No, but that's worse that `<br />`